# Sync Development (SQL 2008) with Production Database (SQL Azure) and want to keep them both in sync all the time. (Schema and the Data)

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization, azure-sql-database

How can I sync my development database (SQL 2008) with Production Database (SQL Azure). I need to keep development and production database both in sync (both schema and the data). How can I do tht????.. Can we do this with VS or TFS or any tool which can help me do this??

Answer (score 0):

yes you can absolutely do it. One of the method is to use DATA SYNC ( http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sqlazure/datasync/ ) which is a no code solution. It is in community technology preview for now

And through VS - you can use SYNC framework to synchronize SQL Azure <-> SQL server. 
resource: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/08/31/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization-using-sync-framework-2-1.aspx

Comment: just a note, neither Sql Azure Data Sync or Sync Framework does schema synchronization.